# Trying to add multiple users on azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

```
declare @Name varchar(100),@sql varchar(400),@sql2 varchar(400),@sql3 varchar(400) ,@sql4 varchar(400) , @psw varchar(10)
--declare @psw varchar(10) = 'Traf@12345'
declare @T table (Name varchar(100)) 
insert into @T values 
('SampleUser1'),
('SampleUser1')
While exists(select * from @T) 
begin 
   select top 1 @Name = name from @T 
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[sql_logins] WHERE [name] = @Name) 
   BEGIN 
      SET @psw = 'Traf@123'
      SET @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN '+'['+@name+']'+' WITH PASSWORD ='+@psw
      EXEC (@sql) 
   END 
   DELETE FROM @T WHERE Name = @Name 
END
```

**output:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
>
> > 'Traf@123'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your question, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following changes:

```
declare @Name varchar(100),@sql varchar(400),@sql2 varchar(400),@sql3 varchar(400) ,@sql4 varchar(400) 
declare @psw varchar(10) = 'Traf@12345';
declare @T table (Name varchar(100)) ;
insert into @T values 
('SampleUser1'),
('SampleUser2')

While exists(select * from @T) 
begin 
   select top 1 @Name = name from @T 
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[sql_logins] WHERE [name] = @Name) 
   BEGIN 

      SET @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN '+'['+@name+']'+' WITH PASSWORD ='''+ @psw + '''; '
      EXEC (@sql) 
   END 
   DELETE FROM @T WHERE Name = @Name 
END
```